# replace () and regex failing to update blank cell

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Can anyone see why the `replace()` in the simple example below is failing to actually replace the blank cell?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'serial_number': ['01a2b345','10ab2030'],'title':['company_a','']}) 

# fill empty cell
data['title'].replace('', np.nan, regex=True) # doesn't work

data
```

I've also attempted to call `data['title'].replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)` with the same result.

I'm sure (as with all of my recent regex issues) I'm overlooking something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `replace` is not an inplace operation, so you need to reassign, i.e. `data['title'] = data['title'].replace('', np.nan, regex=True)`.

Comment: Try adding an `inplace=True` argument.

Answer (score 2):

By default, [`.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) returns an *NDFrame* object which in your case should be reassigned to the original column:

```
In [20]: data.title = data['title'].replace('', np.nan, regex=True)

In [21]: data
Out[21]:
  serial_number      title
0      01a2b345  company_a
1      10ab2030        NaN
```

Alternatively, you could pass the `inplace` parameter as `True`.

Answer (score 2):

The original syntax for replace is:

```
our_str = 'Hello'
new_str = string.replace(our_str, 'you', 'me', 1)
print(new_str)
```

So in your case the code should be:

```
data['title'] = data['title'].replace('', np.nan, regex=True)
```

The reason being that in place replacement is not possible as mentioned by root in the comments.